# Prevent some nagios check for certain hosts

Tags: linux, nagios

Is there a way to configure a certain check to prevent it from running in some hosts of that hostgroup ? I want a check not to run on all the hosts of a hostgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are applying a check to the hostgroup. If so this should work.

In the service definition add a hosts entry line. On that line add a "!hostname-to-exclude".